# How do I change ownership/attributes of a single file or single folder with sbt-native-packager for an RPM?

Tags: scala, rpmbuild, sbt-native-packager

sbt-native-packager, when making an RPM, correctly assigns file ownership as root:root for most files.  I have a case where exactly one configuration file (which doesn't exist in the RPM file, although it could be added if doing so make it easier) needs to be writable by the service.  The easiest way to do this is to change ownership of the conf folder itself, allowing the service to later create that file.  The alternate way is to add the file to the RPM and change ownership of just that one file.

I know I can change the ownership of all configuration files with a stanza like this:

```
linuxPackageMappings in Rpm := {
    linuxPackageMappings.value map {
        case linuxPackage if linuxPackage.fileData.config equals "true" =>
            val newFileData = linuxPackage.fileData.copy(
                user = "newuser",
                group = "newgroup"
            )
            linuxPackage.copy(fileData = newFileData)
        case linuxPackage => linuxPackage
    }
}
```

But:  1) That doesn't change ownership of the **conf folder itself**, and 2) That changes ownership of every single file that is a conf file, which I don't want to do.  Anyway, no matter what I try, the spec file still has:

```
%dir %attr(0755,root,root) /path/to/application/conf/
```

The problem is that it's still owned by root:root.  Here is what I tried, for changing ownership of just the one file (using the above stanza with this case):

```
case linuxPackage if linuxPackage.mappings.head._2 equals "/path/to/application/conf/" =>
```

Also (the answer may be the same), how can I change exactly one configuration file -- selected by filename -- to `withConfig("noreplace")` but not the rest?  I've figured out that linuxPackageMappings is an instance of `Seq[com.typesafe.sbt.packager.linux.LinuxPackageMapping]`, and each instance of LinuxPackageMapping can have one or more file mappings.  I haven't figured out how to remove one mapping from a LinuxPackageMapping and create a new LinuxPackageMapping that contains just the one file.  (Or there may be a better way to do this?)

Comment: Did you find the [Linux Plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/linux.html#customize) documentation? There are some examples on how to alter linuxMappings. There is also a [related issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/575). If the rpm.spec file is incorrect, open a bug or submit a pull request with a failing test :)